# Debug managed v4.5 MVC code on remote IIS8

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, remote-debugging, iis-8

I have a MVC 4 web application that connects to a SQL Server database. It runs fine on the local IIS web server. When I deploy it to an IIS8 web server running on a Windows 2008 Server running on a VMWare VM on the same computer, I get the error "Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request." So, I am trying to debug the application.

I have remote debugger installed and running on the VM and am running it as administrator.  It says WIN-JIIJ\magrawal connected. I use Tools -> Attach to process to connect to WIN-JIIJ:4016 without issues and select W3WP.exe. I also select Managed (v4.5) code in the "Attach to" dropdown.

Now, in Visual Studio, I am trying to enable the ASP.NET debugger in Project -> Properties -> Web -> Debuggers. This gives me the error, "unable to start debugging on the web server ... msvsmon.exe does not appear to be running ... may be because a firewall is preventing ..."

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have spent two days on this now.
Any other method to discover the source of the "sorry, an error occurred ..." message would also be great

Answer (score 1):

Remote debugging now works for me. I have messed with many things. But I believe what did the trick for me was to enable .NET debugging. This is enabled as follows:

In IIS Manager, select the server node in the Connections pane -> ASP.NET category, select .NET compilation -> In the Behaviors group, set Debug = true